# Keras Functional API producing different Results from Keras Sequential API with LSTM Layer

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, tensorflow2.0

I am comparing models built with both the Sequential and Functional API with Keras, and am finding that certain types of models produce very different results.

I am using the IMDB dataset for my model.

If I create a model with only `Embedding` and `Dense` layers, the results are very similar.

Here's an example:

```
# imports
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Dense, LSTM, Flatten, Embedding
from tensorflow.keras import Input, Model
from tensorflow.keras.models import Sequential
from tensorflow.keras.preprocessing.text import Tokenizer
from tensorflow.keras.preprocessing.sequence import pad_sequences
from tensorflow.keras.layers.experimental.preprocessing import TextVectorization
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
```

**CODE FOR SEQUENTIAL API:**

```
df = pd.read_csv('url_for_imdb_csv_file_here')
df['sentiment'].replace(['positive', 'negative'], [1, 0], inplace=True)
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(df['review'], df['sentiment'], test_size=0.2, random_state=1985)
tokenizer = Tokenizer(num_words=10000)
tokenizer.fit_on_texts(X_train)
train_seq = tokenizer.texts_to_sequences(X_train)
test_seq  = tokenizer.texts_to_sequences(X_test)
train_seq = pad_sequences(train_seq, maxlen=250)
test_seq  = pad_sequences(test_seq, maxlen=250)
mod = Sequential([
    Embedding(10000, 25, input_length=250),
    Flatten(),
    Dense(25, activation='relu'),
    Dense(25, activation='relu'),
    Dense(1, activation  = 'sigmoid')
])
mod.compile(optimizer='adam', loss='binary_crossentropy', metrics=['acc'])
mod.fit(train_seq, y_train.values, validation_split=0.2, epochs=2)
```

This produces an accuracy of ~ 88% after two epochs.

If I recreate the same model using the Functional API, I'll get the same results.  Code below.

**CODE USING SEQUENTIAL API**

```
vectorizer = TextVectorization(max_tokens=10000, output_sequence_length=250)
vectorizer.adapt(X_train.values)
text_input = Input(shape=(1,), dtype='string')
x = vectorizer(text_input)
x = Embedding(10000, 25, input_length=250)(x)
x = Flatten()(x)
x = Dense(25, activation='relu')(x)
x = Dense(25, activation='relu')(x)
output = Dense(1, activation='sigmoid')(x)
mod1 = Model(text_input, output)
mod1.compile(optimizer='adam', loss='binary_crossentropy', metrics=['acc'])
mod1.fit(X_train.values, y_train.values, validation_split=0.2, epochs=5)
```

This gives me about the same results.

So far so good.

However, when I try and add LSTM layers, the results diverge significantly.

Here are the two examples I'm using.  I'm swapping out one `Dense` layer with an `LSTM` layer and keeping everything else the same.

**NEW SEQUENTIAL API CODE:**

```
mod = Sequential([
    Embedding(10000, 25, input_length=250),
    LSTM(25),
    Dense(25, activation='relu'),
    Dense(1, activation  = 'sigmoid')
])
mod.compile(optimizer='adam', loss='binary_crossentropy', metrics=['acc'])
mod.fit(train_seq, y_train.values, validation_split=0.2, epochs=2)
```

This gives about the same results as the previous models.

However, when I recreate this version with the functional API, the accuracy peaks at around 64% on round 2, and then heads back down to ~50% after that.

**NEW FUNCTIONAL API:**

```
vectorizer = TextVectorization(max_tokens=10000, output_sequence_length=250)
vectorizer.adapt(X_train.values)
text_input = Input(shape=(1,), dtype='string')
x = vectorizer(text_input)
x = Embedding(10000, 25, input_length=250)(x)
x = LSTM(25)(x)
x = Dense(25, activation='relu')(x)
output = Dense(1, activation='sigmoid')(x)
mod1 = Model(text_input, output)
```

This does not produce the same results, even though it looks the same to me as the `Sequential` example.

Is there something I'm missing that does not make the two the same, or is this an idiosyncrasy of how the Functional API works?

Thank you.

Comment: Take a look at this. https://keras.io/getting_started/faq/#how-can-i-obtain-reproducible-results-using-keras-during-development

Comment: Have you run the last functional model only once, or have you run it multiple times with similar results?

Comment: Also, add the vectorizer to you sequential model for proper comparison.